# Replacing two-character sequences with a single character

Tags: python, arrays, string, replace, character

I am new and working in Python on imported excel datasets.

I am looking for a pythonic way to convert double character sequences into a single character in an entire array. Also, I am trying to do the reverse (one character into two).

For example:

```
File.xlsx["Lexikon"] = ["Maechtig","Schoen","Schluessel","Essen"]

#Pythonic code here

File.xlsx["Lexikon"] = ["Mächtig","Schön","Schlüssel","Eßen"]
```

I honestly have not tried going forward, for though I can use a workaround, I don't feel comfortable with such overwrought code even as a strict beginner. I'm hoping to find a general method, such that I can use my brain to apply the code to other cases without making any unnecessary queries to the floor.

Like, if the order of the characters doesn't matter (`ie` or `ei` becomes `ī`), or if it does (`rw` becomes `g` but not `wr`), and if I am looking to change a three-character sequence (`stl` becomes `d`), I would rather not come back to bother you.

Comment: `str.replace` and `re.sub` are the general solutions to this. read the docs for those methods. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score -2):

To convert double-character sequences into a single character in an array, you can use the replace method of the string class. This method takes two arguments: the old substring to be replaced and the new substring to replace it with. For example, to replace "ae" with "ä", you can use:

```py
s = s.replace("ae", "ä")
```

You can apply this method to each element of the array using a list comprehension or a for loop. For example:

```py
# Using list comprehension
File.xlsx["Lexikon"] = [s.replace("ae", "ä").replace("oe", "ö").replace("ue", "ü").replace("ss", "ß") for s in File.xlsx["Lexikon"]]

# Using for loop
for i in range(len(File.xlsx["Lexikon"])):
s = File.xlsx["Lexikon"][i]
s = s.replace("ae", "ä").replace("oe", "ö").replace("ue", "ü").replace("ss", "ß")
File.xlsx["Lexikon"][i] = s
```

To do the reverse, you can use the same method but with the arguments swapped. For example, to replace "ä" with "ae", you can use:

```py
s = s.replace("ä", "ae")
```

You can also apply this method to each element of the array using a list comprehension or a for loop. For example:

```py
# Using list comprehension
File.xlsx["Lexikon"] = [s.replace("ä", "ae").replace("ö", "oe").replace("ü", "ue").replace("ß", "ss") for s in File.xlsx["Lexikon"]]

# Using for loop
for i in range(len(File.xlsx["Lexikon"])):
s = File.xlsx["Lexikon"][i]
s = s.replace("ä", "ae").replace("ö", "oe").replace("ü", "ue").replace("ß", "ss")
File.xlsx["Lexikon"][i] = s
```

Comment: Please note that use of generative AI to create answers is not allowed on the site. And regardless, if the OP wanted to use ChatGPT, then they would have used it themselves.